# About naming, extension or plugin?

Tags: javascript, naming

We are desiging a javascript UI control library, now we encounter a problem related to naming.

In our case, we design such an architecture that, a special object can be "injected" in our control instance, they have some features like:

- They are "injected" **per instance**, that is, they do not modify out control's `prototype`, they only modify the runtime instance
- They are registered and activated after out control instance is constructed, our controls have a special phase in its life cycle to activate and deactivate them
- They can **modify anything** they like, this includes **listening events**, **overriding certain methods**, **chaning the value of member properties** and more.

So in this case, how should we name them, we have **Extension** and **Plugin** to be choices, we also learnt the differences between **firefox extension** and **firefox plugin** but do not think they are a good reference.

Comment: How about InstanceModifier?

Comment: Seems a bit too complex, to be exact, it should be a **InstanceBehaviorModifier**, this is a good choice :)